# IF no value exists in "IN" statement, show values as '0'

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, exists

I have th following result set for my query (exluding some select statments, joins, and where clauses because I just need the general method of how to accomplish this):

```
Select *
From hsi.itemdata
Where hsi.itemdata.itemtypenum in ('965','502','530','336','513','506','507','514','515','516')
```

```
ItemTypeNum |        ItemType        | DocTypeCount<br/>
502         | Consultation Report    |       4       <br/>
506         | Discharge Summary      |       10       <br/>
336         | ED Nurse Notes    |       2       <br/>
513         | ED Provider Notes    |       8       <br/>
514         | History and Physical    |       15       <br/>
```

I want it to show all even if it doesn't exist in the in statement with a count of '0'.  Like so...

```
ItemTypeNum |        ItemType        | DocTypeCount<br/>
502         | Consultation Report    |       4       <br/>
506         | Discharge Summary      |       10       <br/>
336         | ED Nurse Notes    |       2       <br/>
513         | ED Provider Notes    |       8       <br/>
514         | History and Physical    |       15       <br/>
515         | *Appropriate Value*    |       0       <br/>
516         | *Appropriate Value*    |       0       <br/>
530         | *Appropriate Value*    |       0      <br/>
507         | *Appropriate Value*    |       0       <br/>
965         | *Appropriate Value*    |       0       <br/>
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 2):

In practice, you would use `left join`.  The exact syntax depends on the database.  Here is a version that works in SQL Server and Postgres, for instance:

```
Select v.itemtypenum,
       coalesce(id.ItemType, '*Appropriate Value*') as ItemType,
       coalesce(DocTypeCount, '') as DocTypeCount
From (values ('965'), ('502'), ('530'), ('336'), ('513'), ('506'), ('507'), ('514'), ('515'), ('516')
     ) v(itemtypenum) left join
     hsi.itemdata id
     on id.itemtypenum = v.itemtypenum;
```

Note:  although not all databases support `values` in the `from` clause, almost all have some mechanism for creating a table on the fly.  The idea is the same, but the syntax would be a bit different.

Comment: This works when you have a known list of values for your IN. If the OP is asking about a dynamic list of IN values, it gets a lot more complicated and is likely better handled outside of the query.

Answer (score 1):

One way is by using `CASE` in your select for `DocTypeCount`:

```
SELECT ...
       CASE 
       WHEN hsi.itemdata.itemtypenum IN ('965','502','530','336','513','506','507','514','515','516')
       THEN DocTypeCount
       ELSE 0
       END AS DocTypeCount
FROM hsi.itemdata
```

Of course, this may get more complicated depending on your actual query and how you're getting these columns.